# Change CSS Class by a php function

Tags: php, wordpress

I use a function to initialize a page in my wordpress.

```
function bp_group_calendar_init() {
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/groupcalendar/bp-group-calendar.php' );
}
add_action( 'bp_include', 'bp_group_calendar_init' );
```

Now, I want to change the following css class of my menu:

From:

```
 <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item"><a href="xxxxxx"><strong>Vereine</strong></a><ul class="description">xxx</ul></li>
```

To:

```
 <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="xxxxxx"><strong>Vereine</strong></a><ul class="description">xxx</ul></li>
```

Thank you for your help
Cheers Marc

Comment: How is the code you posted relevant to the question?

Comment: I see that you want to just delete some css classes. What's the motivation behind that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a variable in your PHP called `$classes`.  Fill it with whatever classes will change.

Then change this:

```
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item">
```

to this:

```
<li id="menu-item-28" class="<?php print $classes ?> menu-item...etc">
```

The "...etc" means fill in with whatever classes are not going to be changed by you.